# Upgrade to 14.04 and Keyboard and mouse will not load

Tags: 14.04, usb, keyboard, mouse

I recently upgraded from 13.10 to 14.04 and now I have to unplug the keyboard and mouse and plug them in after the system is booted. I have a Razer Black Widow keyboard and a Corsair mouse. My system is a dual boot Ubuntu/Windows 7 - i7-4770 in a Dell XPS8700
I have no problem with Windows and the USB problem(I assume it's a USB problem) only started after this upgrade. I'm not very familiar with Linux software repairs although I've used Ubuntu for years. I'd like to continue to use it without wearing out my USB ports

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with my XPS8700 in a dual boot with Windows 8.1. What fixed it so far was disabling acpi when booting Ubuntu.

1. When the Grub screen appears,choose the Advanced options for Ubuntu and with the latest kernel selected press "e" on the keyboard to edit the boot options.
2. Navigate with the arrows down to the line that starts with LINUX and just add `acpi=off` to the end of that line.
3. Hit Ctrl + X or F10 to boot, and you should have your mouse and keyboard back.
4. To make this change permanent, so you don't have to do it every time, open a terminal and type:

   ```
   sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
   ```

   Find the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` and append `acpi=off` so that it looks like this: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=off"`

   Save and close the file, then update by running this command from the terminal:

   ```
    sudo update-grub
   ```

It worked for me, hope it helps!!!

Comment: Yes, it worked for me as well. It's been a long time and I haven't had a problem since. Thank you

Answer (score -2):

Here is my answer long and short, Long first, Look in the box your PC came in for your USB and motherboard drivers, they help.
In specific the USB drivers for the ports that are on your specific motherboard.

A trick I learned just to get Windows going, when it freezes at the log in screen: plug a USB mouse in the USB 3.0 port, leave it in while you push the kill button, unplug it after computer shuts down and reboot. Hard to believe but that will get it going one time.

Or

Think, if you do not have a GPS, or special device that requires Windows.

Install Ubuntu on the disk, let it kill Windows and you will have a trouble-free computer. Ubuntu has better office, video, and things you pay for in Windows. I use only Ubuntu in my work computers, I can't afford the problems with Windows.

Comment: Has anyone forced you to answer? Who can claim that Ubuntu has better office? Or for what logical reason one should remove Windows to be able to use mouse and keyboard in a system?!